# anyone have any comment on Business Logic Toolkit for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, business-logic-toolkit

hi
i am taking a look now @ Business Logic Toolkit for .NET http://bltoolkit.net .
but the strange thing is that i dont see anyone using it but from the documentation it seems very nice.
so my question is why there is no one using this library?
i want to use it but i am afraid there is somethings wrong that dont let the people use it.
thanks

Comment: I looked at it a couple of weeks ago actually. It looks solid. Reminds me a bit of the old Microsoft Instrumentation Framework. But note I haven't actually written anything serious with it.

Comment: It seems the project website is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think the problem is that bltoolkit more popular in russia development comunity. Other problems are: no dependecy injection, no full linq support.

Comment: **Main problem**: scarce documentation, almost no community support (at least in English).